# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when call method with Custom Type from Unity to iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, cross-platform, exc-bad-access

I try to build Unity to iOS.

And I have a method call from Unity to iOS,

I can see the details when I hover my mouse on the variable, but when I call the variable, It throw EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Why? Any suggestion.

Here is the code:

Unity call:

```
// call
saveLoginConfig(config);


[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void saveLoginConfig(LinLoginConfig config);
```

Unity object

```
    [Serializable]
    public struct LinLoginConfig
    {
        public bool haveEmail;
    }
```

ios bridge

```
extern void saveLoginConfig(const LinLoginConfig &config) {
    NSLog(@"saveLoginConfig haveEmail0"); // line1
    NSLog(@"saveLoginConfig haveEmail1:%@", &config); // line2
}
```

ios object

```
@interface LinLoginConfig : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, assign) bool haveEmail;

@end
```

---

At breakpoint:
[image]
I can see the detail.

throw:
[image]

Why it happended? help~

## Alternative plan

It maybe not a best Solution, but it works:

just declare the Custom Type in `Objective-C++` file, not in `Objective-C` file.

like this:

```
extern "C" {

class CustomType {
public:
    bool haveEmail;
    ...
};

}
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative plan

It maybe not a best Solution, but it works:

just declare the Custom Type in `Objective-C++` file, not in `Objective-C` file.

like this:

```
extern "C" {

class CustomType {
public:
    bool haveEmail;
    ...
};

}
```

And it works.